Font Awesome doesn't change bullet points in revealjs Quarto
I would like to use Font Awesomes to change my bullet points. I tried using the following code from this question which uses html in my revealjs Quarto presentation:
---
title: "Font Awesome"
format: revealjs
---

# Test

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-regular fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>

Output:

As you can see the bullet points keep the same. I don't understand why we can't use this html syntax to convert the bullet points to a font awesome. The font awesome documentation shows us that it should work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this.

After creating a kit like mentioned by @Limey it does create the bullet points like this:
---
title: "Font Awesome"
format: revealjs
---

# Test

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/954a9d9f43.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-regular fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>

Output:

Unfortunately, you can see the bullet points are still there in the icons.

IIRC, FontAwesome needs soe set up before it "works".  At the risk of asking the obvious, you have done the setup, haven't you?

@Limey, Thank you for your comment. Now I'm able to add the icons but it is overlapping with the still existing bullet points.

From your linked answer, did you try ul { list-style-type: none; } which was suggested in the comments? You can include custom see in a custom theme: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/themes.html#customizing-themes

All the answers were in the comments already, but to put it all together:
---
title: "Font Awesome"
format: revealjs
---

# Test

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/954a9d9f43.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="fa-ul" style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-regular fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>

Or what I prefer to do since it makes things look cleaner:
---
title: "Font Awesome"
format: revealjs
---

# Test

```{=html}
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/954a9d9f43.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="fa-ul" style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa-regular fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```



This works perfectly, thanks!
